# VB.NET CodeDom Compiler (Exclude Version File)

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-construction, codedom

Hey I'm using CodeDom Compiler to compile small scripts to use as plugins in my project.
But I'm curious on removing the version information like seen here:
http://i.gyazo.com/037eae927af5efded1fe8516cc7a69c2.png

I don't want it to be there. I want it gone, but I can't find any option to do so, the vbc.exe compiler doesn't have an argument, and CodeDom doesn't have a method to exclude it.

So does any know how?

This is my source atm:

```
Public Class Codedom
Public Sub GenerateExecutable(ByVal output As String, ByVal source As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim compiler As New VBCodeProvider
    Dim parameters As New CompilerParameters()
    Dim cResults As CompilerResults
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = True
    parameters.OutputAssembly = output
    parameters.WarningLevel = 0
    parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False
    parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = False
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")

    parameters.CompilerOptions = "/optimize+ /platform:AnyCPU /removeintchecks+ /filealign:512 /define:_MYTYPE=\""None\"""
    Dim version = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    version.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0")
    cResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source)
    If cResults.Errors.Count > 0 Then 'Line
        For Each CompilerError In cResults.Errors
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " & CompilerError.ErrorText & " Line: " & CompilerError.Line)
        Next
    ElseIf cResults.Errors.Count = 0 Then
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class